# Handlebars Dynamic Partial Block

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a folder structure like so:

```
- components/
  - foo/
     - index.js
     - foo.handlebars
     - foo.scss
  - bar/
     - index.js
     - bar.handlebars
     - bar.handlebars
```

In order to resolve component partials conveniently I provide a helper that will find a correct path, translating `bar` into `components/bar/bar.handlebars`. This helper is called `getPartialForTemplate`.

In my template, I do:

`{{> (getPartialForTemplate 'foo') some=props}}`

This is fine, but when I need to use the resolved template as a block I come across an issue:

```
{{#> (getPartialForTemplate 'foo')}}
  <p>Some text here..</p>
{{/WHATGOESHERE???}}
```

This seems like a syntax flaw in Handlebars, as I'd expect its syntax features to work together. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand how you think this should work. Where would `<p>Some text here..</p>` go? Before or after the "foo" partial?

Comment: Neither. It should go within the partial, and the partial will decide where to place the text using `{{> @partial-block }}`.

I looked at the parser and it appears to exclude the use of *sexpr*, only *partialName*, so it required a non-sexpr identifier when using block partials.

I tried cheating and using `{{#with (getPartialForTemplate 'foo')}} {{#> this}}<p>...</p>{{/this}}{{/with}}`, but that won't work because the `this` keyword is parsed as a *partialName*, and not an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1371) on github, the suggested workaround is this:

```
{{#>( lookup . 'intendedTemplate' )}}
  No template matched for "{{intendedTemplate}}"
{{/undefined}}
```