# Lookup partial for dynamic paths in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, handlebars.js, partials

I'm looking to dynamically load partials based on whatever the input vars are.

My handlebars looks like:
`{{> (lookup . 'hbs') }}`

Where `hbs` is the relative path of where the partial is. So say my folder structure is like this:

```
views
-> components
---> component.hbs
-> project
---> partial.hbs
```

If var `hbs = '../project/partial'`, I get the error: `The partial ../project/partial could not be found`.

When I write: `{{> ../project/partial }}`, the page compiles as expected. Of course, I need this to be dynamic, so it doesn't really solve my issue.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049761/handlebars-dynamic-partial-block) solution, but it does not work for me. Let me know if I can or should elaborate on anything that may be helpful. Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using handlebars-webpack-plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-webpack-plugin)?

Comment: Yes I am using that plugin

Comment: The `{{> (lookup . 'hbs') }}` works for me. However, my partial IDs do not start with `../` - I am actually uncertain how you were able to get this working with `../` prefixed partial IDs. Would you be able to share the `partials` Array value in the config object you pass to the HandlebarsPlugin constructor in your webpack config?